# Removing the "[]" from an ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> println

Tags: java, arraylist

Hoping to find a way to remove the "[]" that encloses the output of my code.

Controller:

```
view.linesDisplay(model.getFpData().getLines(100,103));
```

ArrayList<ArrayList> code.

```
@Override
public ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> getLines(int firstLine, int lastLine) {
    ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> listLines = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
    
    for (int i = firstLine; i < lastLine; i++){
        listLines.add(getLine(i));
        
    }
    return listLines;
```

And the print side:

```
public void linesDisplay(ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> arrOfarr)
{    
    for (ArrayList<String> s : arrOfarr)
    {
        System.out.println(s + " ");
    }

}
```

Output is:

```
[62, G, Zach Simpson, 6'3", 272, Hollidaysburg, Pa., Hollidaysburg Area] 
[24, S, Anthony Smith, 6'0", 206, Dover, N.J., Pope John XXIII]
[47, LB, Brandon Smith, 6'0", 223, Winfield, Pa., Lewisburg]
```

Please let me know if there's anything more you need to know.

Comment: And what is your actual output ?

Comment: My output is: 
[62, G, Zach Simpson, 6'3", 272, Hollidaysburg, Pa., Hollidaysburg Area] 
[24, S, Anthony Smith, 6'0", 206, Dover, N.J., Pope John XXIII] 
[47, LB, Brandon Smith, 6'0", 223, Winfield, Pa., Lewisburg]

I will add that to the main post.

Comment: Please see [ask] and [mcve]

Comment: Don't post critical information in comments. Edit the question.

Comment: Such as Mad said, some data are missing; waht is the `getLine` method ? What are the begin object/line ? It seems to just print an object like `[id, name]`

Answer (score 2):

You can use `String#substring` to remove the first and last characters.

```java
for (ArrayList<String> s : arrOfarr){
    String str = s.toString();   
    System.out.println(str.substring(1, str.length() - 1));
}
```

Comment: Why not replace first `[` and last `]` ? Because maybe first char is space

Comment: @Elikill58 When would the first character be a space? Using `replace` is slower and there is no need to do so when the positions of the characters are fixed.

Comment: I agree with what @Unmitigated said. The ArrayList toString implementation starts with `[` and ends with `]` and would never change unless there is a change to the Java source code

Answer (score 1):

By concatenating `s`, you're implicitly calling the default collection [`toString()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/AbstractCollection.html#toString--), which joins the elements on `", "` and encloses it all in brackets. You can do the join yourself and omit the brackets:

```
System.out.println(String.join(", ", s) + " ");
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a list-of-a-list. Thus, you need a for-in-a-for.

> `linesDisplay(ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> arrOfarr)`

> ```
> for (ArrayList<String> s : arrOfarr)
>    {
>        System.out.println(s + " ");
>    }
> ```

This tries to execute `s + " "`; given that `s` is an arbitrary object, and the right hand side is specifically a string, java sees this as string concatenation, and turns the object into a string by calling `.toString()` on that list. That is the source of your `[]`.

Either write another for loop (inside that for loop), or use a string joiner from various libraries, or use the joining collector:

```
String whatYouWanted = String.join(", ", s);
```

The `join` method will take a collection of String objects (`s`, here), and concatenates them together, using the provided string as infix separator. Contrast with `s.toString()`, which does that **and** adds those `[` and `]` you want to get rid of.

```
list.stream().collect(Collectors.joining(","));
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the `toString()` method, which is called by `println()` (whether or not you print `s + " "` or just `s`), of `List` wraps a csv of its elements in `[` and `]`.

So instead use `String.join()`:

```
public void linesDisplay(List<List<String>> arrOfarr) {    
    for (List<String> s : arrOfarr) {
        System.out.println(String.join(", ", s));
    }
}
```

Note also best practice of using the abstract type `List` instead of the concrete type `ArrayList` - see [Liskov substitution principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle).

Answer (score 0):

You have a list of lists. When you are iterating first time, you go over the inner arraylists. So when printing `(s + " ")` you print the whole arraylist. You should iterate one more time inside the first loop to print the actual items of arraylists.

```
for (ArrayList<String> s : arrOfarr)
    {
        for (String item : s)
        {
            System.out.println(item + " ");
        }
    }
```

And you can learn [java streams](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html) to handle this even better